# How to make h2 mobile responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I’m trying to achieve the following, when the screen size is a mobile size, I want my HTML to listen to the class in my CSS, @media tag class “.new”, how do I achieve this?

Desktop CSS below:

```
h2{
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

Mobile Device CSS below:

```
@media (max-width:600px) {
  .new {
  font-size: 24px;
  }}
```

My current html, I guess I would need to add another div wrap i.e. to the HTML to override this? not exactly sure, please advice, in how to make my code listen to .new class when its a mobile size as above?

```
        <div class="list-group-item">
        <h2>HELLOWORLD
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></h2>
        </div>
```

Comment: Why do you need the `.new` class? Can't you just target `h2` in the media query?

Comment: You're targeting the `new` class which doesn't exist in the html you've provided. `<h2 class="new">HELLOWORLD</h2>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would remove your "new" class and add a media-specific CSS rule for the `<h2>` element.

**UPDATE**

Since you don't want this responsive behavior to be applied to all of your `<h2>` elements, you can use a class and define your CSS rule with that class.

Here's an example:

```css
h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
}

@media (max-width:600px) {
  h2.responsive {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="list-group-item">
  <h2 class="responsive">
    HELLOWORLD
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
  </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: H2 is used somewhere else to.

Comment: Alright -- I've edited the example to leverage a class.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `class="new"` to your `<h2>`, like that:

```
<h2 class="new">HELLOWORLD <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></h2>
```

Comment: can we add a full answer please?

Comment: do I leave the existing <h2> in my HTML and add another one this time <h2 class??

Comment: @Waq No need. Just add the class to your existing `<h2>` tag. It should do the trick.